# How to check my permissions

Tags: permissions, service-account

I have been getting mixed answers regarding this question. How can I find out what permissions I have in a Sharepoint farm? I'm pretty new to it and I have been told that I have a farm account but on certain sites I don't have access. Can someone please assist so I can clarify myself on what rights/permissions I have?

Answer (score 6):

**A SharePoint Farm is like a Business Park:**
[image]

**then Site Collections are Buildings:**
As [Site Collection Owner](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Permissions-for-site-collection-administrators-f7f82b3e-7ef3-4938-a49b-9504de3b6c2a) you have a **MasterKey** to all information in this building.
[Permission Profiles](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/understanding_sharepoint_and_office365_permission_levels) can be centrally managed, *but **alas** most often not customized*
[image]

**Subsites (Webs) are Rooms:**
[image]

**Document Libraries/Lists are Cabinets:**
[image]

**Documents-Sets/Folders are File Suspension Holders:**
[DocumentSets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-c49c246d-31f1-4bfe-afe2-e26698b47e05) are available since SP2010 and underestimated by many
(*and most often completely unknown*)
[image]

**and Documents/List Items are Files:**
with metadata
[image]

### Permissions to all

On each of the above you can have different locks(permission profiles) (each can have 33 types of SharePoint [permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) to be precise).
**And you have to check each one to see what permissions you have**

Either by hand or a Powershell script.
Search can give you a clue where you have Read rights (but you can have *Write* rights without *Read* rights..)

**OMG!** In the digital world you can have access to  a File and **NOT** have access to the File-Holder or Cabinet or Room or Building or Business Park.

Ah... [Governance](http://blog.epcgroup.net/security-governance-sharepoint-bestpractices-sharepoint2013-office365-epcgroup/)

*Most will try and sell you 3rd party tools to manage this all... but if your foundation is crap, no tool can fix it for you*

Just like an architect plans every detail of a building, good [Permissions planning for sites and content in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262939.aspx) is key

iSPT

Comment: Yeah, this deserves an up-vote strictly for the outstanding analogy.